# Brackets spanning multiple lines in a single column inside table

Tags: tables, spacing, xetex, brackets

I would like to typeset round brackets so that they span multiple lines inside a tabular environment, but only for a specific column. In the example below, I would like the brackets to appear around the last (fourth) column.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\newcommand{\da}{\ensuremath{\downarrow}}
\newcommand{\ua}{\ensuremath{\uparrow}}
\newcommand{\ra}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{tabular}[t]{cccc}
VP & \ra & V & NP \\
& & \ua~=~\da & (\ua~\textsc{obj}) = \da\\
\end{tabular}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

How would I go about doing that, preferrably in a non-math context? BTW: I'm using XeLaTeX (yes, I'm aware that I could be using the Unicode symbols for the arrows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with the commands `\ldelim` and `\rdelim` provided by the [`bigdelim`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigdelim) package.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}


\newcommand{\da}{\ensuremath{\downarrow}}
\newcommand{\ua}{\ensuremath{\uparrow}}
\newcommand{\ra}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{tabular}[t]{cccc@{}c@{}c}
VP & \ra & V & \ldelim({2}{3mm} & NP & \rdelim){2}{0mm} \\
& & \ua~=~\da & & (\ua~\textsc{obj}) = \da & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it with a uniform syntax, with the help of `delarray`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\usepackage{delarray}

\newcommand{\da}{\ensuremath{\downarrow}}
\newcommand{\ua}{\ensuremath{\uparrow}}
\newcommand{\ra}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\specification}{\@ifstar{\spec@line{(}{)}}{\spec@line{}{}}}
\newcommand{\spec@line}[4]{%
  $\begin{array}[t]#1{@{}>{$}c<{$}@{}}#2
  #3\\#4
  \end{array}$%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
VP \ra\ \specification{V}{\ua\ = \da} \specification*{NP}{\ua\ \textsc{obj} = \da}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image]